# How to use IFrame within TinyMCE

Tags: html, asp.net, tinymce, html-editor

I used TinyMCE editor with ASP.Net. But it has no any IFrame supportive features, Such as Embed YouTube Video. Is there any plugins for TinyMCE or Is there any alternative for this.

Thanks...

Comment: Which version of TinyMCE are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one of alternative ([CK Editor](http://ckeditor.com/)) which supports Iframe and flash content. It has plugins which related to embed YouTube videos directly. Really good solution.